Как изменить цвета в Android TimePicker?
Пишу приложение. Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог выбирать дату и время.
С DatePicker разобрался. Однако с TimePicker никак не получается.
Вот код вызова:
private void showTimePickerDialog(final boolean isStartDate) {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, R.style.CustomTimePickerDialog, (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            if (isStartDate) {
                startDateTimeView.setText(String.format("%tF %tT", dateAndTime, dateAndTime));
                showDatePickerDialog(false);
            } else {
                stopDateTimeView.setText(String.format("%tF %tT", dateAndTime, dateAndTime));
            }
        }, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);

        timePickerDialog.show();
    }

А вот стили:
<style name="CustomTimePickerDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="showTitle">false</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffd600</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#b71c1c</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#43a047</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#f44336</item>
        <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#D71000</item>
        <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#0036D7</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="statusBarBackground">@color/background</item>

    </style>

Вот текущий вид:

Какие-то стили работают. Например textColorPrimary, colorControlActivated и textColorSecondary. Но при этом фон не меняется, цвет цифр не меняется, заголовка тоже.
Подскажите, как мне поменять?
UPD:
ответ iramm помог. Однако встал новый вопрос. Внизу есть доп кнопка для ввода текста с клавы телефона.
Как мне кнопку эту убрать или стилизовать новое окошко.
Теперь такие стили:
    <style name="CustomTimePickerDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="showTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffd600</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/main_color</item>
        <item name="android:numbersTextColor">@color/main_color</item>
        <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="statusBarBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">@color/main_color</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
        <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

Скриншот окна второго


Здесь имеют значение, что задано в качестве родительских тем/стилей.
 <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here.-->
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/MyTimePickerLight</item>
</style>

<!-- Light Time Picker-->
<style name="CustomTimePickerDialog" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#1565C0</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">#673AB7</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#FFEB3B</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#61E761</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFC107</item>
</style>

Theme.AppTheme - тема приложения, указанная в AndroidManifest.xml.

Большое спасибо. Это действительно помогло.  Но я бы хотел узнать, а как настроить стили для альтернативного режима, вы случайно не знаете?  Слева внизу появляется значок с клавиатурой. При нажатии окошко меняется и там можно вручную ввести время. Я бы хотел либо его отключить, либо как-то стилизовать. Скриншот в обновлении

Здравствуйте. Рада, что ответ помог. Но мне кажется, что в логике сайта stackoverflow вы должны зачесть мой ответ как верный. И далее не уточнять старую версию вопроса, а задать новый вопрос. У меня, например, тогда бы существенно усилилась мотивация найти ответ на ваш новый вопрос.

Справедливо. Принимаю и задам новый вопрос.
